# Facebook Website OAuth Login Blank

Tags: javascript, facebook, parse-platform, facebook-oauth

Hi StackOverFlow peeps,

Issue: we are using Parse.com to login users. When user chooses to authenticate with FB (an unfortunate act), a popup comes up like it should, and user graciously enters their username and password. From there it gets a little mad. The popup goes blank and the URL reads

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?app_id= ...

I've banged my head against many google searches for 3-4 days, and the dude at FB bug tracking isn't much help (sorry Rafael). I've seen others with same issue, but no clear answer. Our FB login code is as simple as toast and butter:

```
 Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn("email,user_friends", {
//success or error never called
                success: function(user) {
                    console.log(user);
```

We follow the instructions on Parse and FB to the T, and at this point going nuts.

Additional details:

We have multiple subdomains, but to test things out we move the login to our main domain, and made according changes to our fb app settings, same issue.

We even though it might be Parse! so we tried the regular old FB login (no luck).

Any tips, prayers, voodoo, or straight up code will be humbly accepted.

Comment: _“so we tried the regular old FB login”_ – what did that look like exactly? And what’s the actual URL to the login dialog in that case?

Comment: Exactly same behavior, no error no warning, just a blank popup.

Comment: I was rather asking for code and an actual URL of the login dialog call …

Comment: Try removing your facebook app secret from settings in parse app dashboard.

Comment: We tried all that, and actually earlier today it was working, and then it stopped working again. Nothing is different in code from when it was working and when it stopped.